# Color cells in a column in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I currently have a JTable consisting of 7 columns and many rows of data.

How would I go about colour each cell in the 7th column? I want to colour according to the data inside the cell.

So if one of the cells in the 7th column was say below 0, then I want to colour red or if one of the cells in the 7th column was more than 0, then colour green etc.

Thank you

Comment: @deporter  Ehhh.. (shrugs)  I just move along to the next question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you are right.

Comment: Sorry, I've just learnt how to and will do so from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a TableCellRenderer to create these custom styles for individual cells in the table. This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) explains in some detail. On that page is an example that uses a color renderer which may be the start that you need.

Answer (score 2):

Override `prepareRenderer()` method when you initialize your table object, put your specific conditionals to change colors accordingly, then color changes will be reflected in your application as you defined. Suppose you have a global JTable variable `table` and let `model` be your DefaultTableModel instance:

```
table = new JTable( model )
{
    public Component prepareRenderer ( TableCellRenderer r, int row, int col )
    {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer( r, row, col );
        if ( col == 6 && !isCellSelected( row, col ) )
        {
            if ( table.getValueAt( row, col ) < 0 )
                comp.setBackground( Color.RED );
            else
               comp.setBackground( Color.GREEN );
        }  
        return comp;
    }
};
```

The code above is checking for `col == 6` because you want to colorize 7th column, which corresponds to column index 6 (it starts from 0). In the inner if statement, it is checking for cell values and changing cell background color accordingly.

Comment: while doable, I would not recommend it in this use case which requires a visual decoration on a particular column: that's a "lightweight" task a custom renderer is designed to handle. A table override, on the other hand, is a "heavyweight" measure: keep in mind that - as a general rule - JSomething should not be extended at all for application needs, they are designed to be used.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for your constructive comment. i will try to use this comment for upcoming issues.